# How to achieve horizontally centered layout with partially liquid column?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a request to make a HTML/CSS 3-column layout that meets these criteria:

- middle and right column have a fixed width
- left column has a max-width
- the 3 columns are horizontally centered
- ff the browser's viewport gets shrinked and the left border of the left column touches the left border of the viewport, then, by further shrinking the viewport, the left column starts shrinking in width until width is 0. (like in [this example](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm), except for that here the left column also has a min-width).

I could not find such a layout. If it is possible, how do I achieve this? (Telling me, it's not possible, would also earn the checkmark).

Comment: learn and do it __yourself!!!__.. if you come across any problem - come back and ask!!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a guide to [responsive layouts](http://designfestival.com/resizing-fixed-fluid-or-responsive-layouts/) and another to some [responsive frameworks](http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/17/15-responsive-css-frameworks-worth-considering/) you might consider using to achieve what you need to.

> **Generally it's good ettiqute on the stack network to try and create code yourself and then post specific questions if you get
>   stuck.**

Comment: I was/am looking for a basic concept, not for code. This is why I couldn't have been more specific and decided not to post my humble attempts.

Comment: @Mathias I understand, the concepts should be available in the links I provided, the arena you're looking for is responsive design and searching Google for that term may be helpful to you. You might also find some useful examples on template sites like themeforest.com